# Row value manipulation in R based on condition

Tags: r

Below shows my data frame.

```
dataframe <-
  data.frame(
    A = c(0, 13.4375, 13.625, 16.6875, 16.6875),
    B = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    c = c(3, 9, 63, 52, 98)
  )

#dataframe
    #A             B      c    
    #0            0       3  
    #13.4375      0       9  
    #13.625       0       63  
    #16.6875      +1      52  
    #16.6875      +1      98  
    #..           ..      ..
```

And the values continues till `n rows`.
Now I am interested in only first few rows, say 3 rows for examples(It will be declared as variable `w`). I would like to change values in `c` based on the values in `B`, The condition is if there is any values in `B` other than 0, I would like to retain the values that is in `c`for the value of `w`. else I would want to replace the data in `c` as `0` for number of rows declared in `w`

`w == 3` then **Expected output is**

```
    A             B      c    
    0             0      0  
    13.4375       0      0  
    13.625        0      0  
    16.6875      +1      52  
    16.6875      +1      98
```

Comment: Will w always be of fixed length?

Comment: @no, It will be a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is this it?

```
dataframe = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4), 
                       B = c(1,0,0,1), 
                       C = c(0,0,0,1))

w <- 3
dataframe$C[1:w] <- ifelse(dataframe$B[1:w] == 0, 0, dataframe$B[1:w])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example showed, we multiply the 'B' with 'C' column to replace the 'C' values to 0 for those having 0 in 'B'

```
df1$C <- df1$B*df1$C
```

But, if there are values in 'B' other than 0 and 1 and we need to only replace the first 3 elements (if it is 0 on 'B')

```
df1$C[1:3] <- df1$B[1:3]*df1$C[1:3]
```

On further making the condition a bit more complex,

```
w <- 3
i1 <- (seq_len(nrow(df1)) %in%  seq_len(w)) & df1$B ==0
df1$C <- df1$C * !i1
```

Comment: This replaces all the values of `c`, but I am interested to change only those number of rows which will be declared in `w`

Comment: @Tareva Updated the post